# Unable to resolve symbol error in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Here is my code.

```
(use '[leiningen.exec :only (deps)])
(deps '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
       [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]])
(deps '[[clj-http "0.5.8"]
       [org.clojars.rorygibson/clj-amazon "0.3.0-SNAPSHOT"]]
  )

(def ACCESS-KEY "my access key" )
(def SECRET-KEY "my secret key" )
(def ASSOCIATE-ID "my id")

(def ENDPOINT "webservices.amazon.co.uk") 

(def signer (signed-request-helper ACCESS-KEY SECRETE-KEY ASSOCIATE-ID))

(def gibson-opus-search (item-search :signer signer :search-index "Books", :keywords "Neuromancer", :associate-tag ASSOCIATE-ID, :condition "New"))

(def lookup-specific-item (item-lookup :signer signer :associate-tag ASSOCIATE-ID :item-id "B0069KPSPC" :response-group   "ItemAttributes,OfferSummary"))
```

I'm trying to use Amazon's product api on Clojure. When I try lein exec on the command prompt, I get unable to resolve symbol: signed-request helper in this context. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using lein deps instead of a defproject for a particular reason?  That error suggests that your dependencies are not being successfully included.

Answer (score 2):

The `deps` call sets up the classpath so your dependencies are available. You'll need to `require` a namespace to load it and then `refer` (within the `require`) to make those external symbols available to your code. Or alternately, you can `use` the external namespace to both load and `refer` (although this is generally discouraged stylistically these days).

In this example:

```
(require '[clj-amazon.core :refer [signed-request-helper]]
         '[clj-amazon.product-advertising :refer [item-search item-lookup])
```

Or:

```
(use 'clj-amazon.core
     'clj-amazon.product-advertising)
```

Generally the `require` version is preferred because it is then visually traceable where functions used in your code came from.

Answer (score 1):

You never define `signed-request-helper` in that context, so of course it unresolvable.  You need to either provide a definition or, if it's included in one of the dependencies, you need to `use` or `require` the appropriate namespace.